# How to include library project in library project in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, library-project

I have a library project(Project A) in Eclipse that itself depends on a library project(Project B). How to include the Project A and Project B(on which Project A depends) as a library project in my Android Studio main Project (Project M)? I know the answer of how to include a single library project. But my question is how to include a library project which itself depends on a library project.

Comment: This is already answered in the following link:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/16639227/2688378

Comment: @SubinM I know the answer of how to include a single library project. But my question is how to include a library project which itself depends on a library project. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to include both library projects (A and B) in your main project (M). Android Studio doesn't support a module with transitive dependencies on other modules that aren't specifically defined in the project's **settings.gradle** file.